# MS Access query produces invalid procedure call

Tags: sql, ms-access

My query in access works fine if i only use the below query with a select statement. As soon as it becomes an append query it produces an "invalid procedure call" error.

I have narrowed down the offending columns as being "Publ" and "PublLong". Both are long text strings. If I remove these two columns the query updates without an error.

Here is a sample data point found in the `[Bezeichung]` Field:

> publications.bank.com/publ-dl-ch/pdf/WhatsUp_20181113_en.pdf

I checked the table that it is being inserted to and the data types are the same nor did i see any other setting that would block the insertion.

**How can i get it to work?**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_MatomoRaw ( DownloadDate, IntExt, Publ, PublLong, 
                            PublDate, [Language], Download_Visits, PublMonth )
SELECT 
    Date() AS DownloadDate, 
    Left([Bezeichnung],InStr([Bezeichnung],".")-1) AS IntExt, 
    Nz(Mid([Bezeichnung],InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")+1,InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")-
        InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")-1),"") AS Publ, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")+1,InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"_")-
        InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")-1) AS PublLong, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")+1,8) AS PublDate, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],Len([Bezeichnung])-5,2) AS [Language],
    xlsx_Output.[Eindeutige Downloads] AS Download_Visits, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")+1,6) AS PublMonth
FROM xlsx_Output
WHERE 
    (((Nz(Mid([Bezeichnung],InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")+1,InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")-
        InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")-1),"")) Not Like "#Func!"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#Func!` indicates one of your functions is causing an error.

Your query uses multiple functions that run into trouble when your input doesn't meet that format, pre-filter instead of filtering on an error, since you can't filter on an error when appending:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_MatomoRaw ( DownloadDate, IntExt, Publ, PublLong, 
                            PublDate, [Language], Download_Visits, PublMonth )
SELECT 
    Date() AS DownloadDate, 
    Left([Bezeichnung],InStr([Bezeichnung],".")-1) AS IntExt, 
    Nz(Mid([Bezeichnung],InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")+1,InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")-
        InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")-1),"") AS Publ, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")+1,InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"_")-
        InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")-1) AS PublLong, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")+1,8) AS PublDate, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],Len([Bezeichnung])-5,2) AS [Language],
    [Eindeutige Downloads] AS Download_Visits, 
    Mid([Bezeichnung],InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")+1,6) AS PublMonth
FROM (SELECT * FROM xlsx_Output WHERE Len(Bezeichnung) > 5 AND Bezeichnung LIKE "*?.?*" AND Bezeichnung LIKE "*_????????*" AND Bezeichnung LIKE "*?\?*")
WHERE 
    (((Nz(Mid([Bezeichnung],InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")+1,InStr([Bezeichnung],"_")-
        InStrRev([Bezeichnung],"/")-1),"")) Not Like "#Func!"));
```

Since I don't know exactly where the errors occur, I can't write up a proper filter to identify them, but judging by your query they should include a slash and a symbol after that slash, an underscore and at least 8 symbols after that underscore, and a dot with at least one symbol before and after the dot.

Comment: Thank you for the hint that I need to prefilter and can't do it in one step. This was driving me nuts. After writing a query that prefiltered out errors it now works perfeclty. Cheers!